# Measuring the performance of VNC feeds

Tags: performance-testing, vnc-server

We have a web application which connects to a remote server through VNC. The user do some use cases on the VNC server through this connection.

I want to do the performance testing of the use cases. How to measure the speed (performance) of the VNC feed from my web application to the VNC server?

I could not find anything with JMeter or Load runner tools, Is there any tools available to measure this?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using a VNC client library like [vernacular-vnc](https://github.com/shinyhut/vernacular-vnc) or [TightVNC-Java-Viewer](https://github.com/andy-w/TightVNC-Java-Viewer) in order to connect to the VNC server and consume the video stream and/or send some client actions

The libraries can be used from i.e [JSR223 Test Elements using Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) or you can [develop your own JMeter plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-develop-a-jmeter-plugin-intro-and-best-practices)

Comment: Our application is connecting to the remote server through cloud. and not directly by giving IP and port number. How to simulate the screen rendering of the remote server in this scenario?